# Using after_commit transaction hook in Ruby's Sequel

Tags: ruby, transactions, sequel

I'm making a series of updates to my Postgres database. Halfway through these updates I need to run a chunk of code which also modifies the database, *but must not be inside a transaction*.

I've discovered the `DB.after_commit` transaction hook, which seems to be perfect, except that it doesn't behave how I would expect:

```
acc = []
acc << ["before", DB.in_transaction?]
DB.transaction do
    acc << ["inside", DB.in_transaction?]
    SomeModel.create(value: "foo")
    DB.after_commit {
        acc << ["after_commit", DB.in_transaction?]
    }
end
acc << ["after", DB.in_transaction?]
```

I would expect `acc` to be `[["before",false],["inside",true],["after_commit",false],["after",false]]`, but I am seeing `[["before",false],["inside",true],["after_commit",true],["after",false]]`

Is there a way to prevent the callback from being run inside a transaction?

Comment: I've just been watching the postgres logs. I can see the BEGIN and COMMIT statements in the correct places, so perhaps the transaction has completed as expected, and `in_transaction?` is just returning an incorrect value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Database#in_transaction?` is apparently not accurate inside an `after_commit` block.  But `after_commit` is definitely being called after the `COMMIT` happens, not before.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Sequel's master branch, and should ship in Sequel 4.21.0.